# Displaying the content of an input for several divs

Tags: javascript, html, class

I want to give all .firstname-show the content from the input but I don't know how to do it. Here's code:

```
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
    <button id="firstname-btn" onclick="show()">SHOW</button>
    <div class="firstname-show"></div>
    <div class="firstname-show"></div>
```

```
    function show() {
       var name = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
       document.querySelectorAll('.firstname-show').textContent = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query selector will return an array so you have to iterate using for loop. see below function.

```
function show() {
    var name = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.firstname-show');

    for(var i in elements){
        elements[i].textContent = name;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kagf25c1/

Answer (score 0):

Since the querySelectorAll returns a collection, you can use the forEach method on the collection to browse each element and apply the processing you want

```js
const show = () => {
     let value = document.getElementById('firstname').value;
     document.querySelectorAll('.firstname-show')
     .forEach(div => div.textContent = value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First name">
<button id="firstname-btn" onclick="show()">SHOW</button>
<div class="firstname-show"></div>
<div class="firstname-show"></div>
```